# Linear Regression: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'G3' not found

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I am trying to use a multiple linear regression algorithm in a data set. The attribute I am trying to predict is named G3. 
I tried to do this:

```
d1=read.table("student-mat.csv",sep=";",header=TRUE)

train <- d1[1:356,]
test <- d1[357:395,]
fit2 <- lm(G3 ~ famrel + G1 + G2, data=train)
coefficients(fit2)
```

It worked with no errors. 
Then I tried to do cross-validation, so I did this:

```
install.packages("DAAG")
library(DAAG)
cv.lm( form.lm = fit2, m=3, dots=FALSE) # 3 fold cross-validation
```

But the last line gave me this error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'G3' not found

I can't understand why. I searched for this error, and it normally happens when the object is not in the data frame, which is not the case. Can someone tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seemed to have missing the data argument in `cv.lm`, that is why R is not able to find G3 object. It should be like below:

```
library(DAAG)
cv.lm(data= mtcars, mpg ~ drat + hp, m= 3)
```

I am using here `mtcars` data, you can try with your data and let me know. It should work

Comment: Thank's for your answer. In my case, mtcars should be fit2? I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: @Person NO , It should be your data name `d1` not the model name, fit2 is your model name not data name.